# stream output of a command continuously run in php

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell, output-buffering

i am running this simple command

```
{ ./a.out < in; } &> output.txt
```

using exec and i want to **output** what's coming in output.txt through ajax request **continuously**. 
Also i want a way to turn off my output buffering.I tried flush() and ob functions but didn't succedded.In my

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  php.ini
```

value of

```
output_buffering = 4096
error in log file is:
[Sat May 31 15:48:26.853420 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1277] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat May 31 17:23:30.461926 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1270] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4 configured -- resuming normal     operations
[Sat May 31 17:23:30.484232 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1270] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

.When I change it to Off and restart my apache2 server it fails to restart.
P.S. I am using lamp server.

Comment: "it fails to restart." does not really help. What happens? What is the error message, what is in the log files?

Comment: The main challenge here is to reliably find the right offset between separate ajax requests. So what portion of that output file actually is new after the last request. You need some persistent pointer indicating what has already been transferred, since you cannot remove the already transferred portion from the file without interrupting the generating process. This also would mean that the file size would grow endlessly, which obviously is not a good idea.

Comment: [Fri May 30 23:39:06.575881 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1226] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down                           [Sat May 31 14:24:57.925598 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1277] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4 configured -- resuming normal     operations
[Sat May 31 14:24:57.981741 2014] [core:notice] [pid 1277] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: Please add additional information by using the `edit` button below the question. Do _not_ add additional information inside comments. It is too hard to read and see at all.